# How to make a chomping effect in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Here's my code:

```
    import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pac-Man")

# Sets the size of the screen via (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 478
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 608
# Speed of Characters
SPEED = 1
# Frames per second, how fast the game runs
FPS = 50
# Colors (RED,GREEN,BLUE)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

HIGH_SCORE = 0

# Sets the WIDTH and HEIGHT of the window
WINDOW = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
# Displays the screen
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

PacManStartSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load 
                                           ("PacManStart.png"), (24, 24))
PacManStartSurface.convert()
PacManStartRect = PacManStartSurface.get_rect(topleft = 
                                             (((SCREEN_WIDTH - 25) // 2),
                                             (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 144) // 2))

PacManSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load 
                                      ("PacManRight.png"), (24, 24))
PacManSurface.convert()
PacManRect = PacManStartSurface.get_rect(topleft = 
                                        (((SCREEN_WIDTH - 125) // 2),
                                        (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 144) // 2))

CurrentSurface = PacManStartSurface
CurrentRect = PacManStartRect 

BackgroundSurface = pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

class PacMan():
    def __init__(self):
        self.LIVES = 3
        
class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("PowerUp.png")
                                            .convert(), (23, 23))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
class YellowGhost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load
                                           ("YellowGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (235, 347))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
class RedGhost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("RedGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (235, 347))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
class BlueGhost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("BlueGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (235, 347))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
class PinkGhost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("PinkGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (235, 347))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
class Maze():
    def __init__(self):
        self.DOTS = []
        self.WALLS = []
        self.BLOCK_WIDTH = 25
        self.BLOCK_HEIGHT = 25
        self.MAZE_OFFSET_X = 0
        self.MAZE_OFFSET_Y = 50
        self.MARGIN = 3
        # 0 - Dots
        # 1 - Walls
        # 2 - Power Up
        # 3 - Empty Space
        # 4 - Ghosts
        self.MATRIX = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [3,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,3], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,4,4,4,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,0], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [3,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,3], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1], \
                      [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                      
        # BackgroundImage(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.MAZE_X = self.BLOCK_WIDTH * (len(self.MATRIX[0]) 
                      + self.MAZE_OFFSET_X)
        self.MAZE_Y = self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * (len(self.MATRIX)
                      + self.MAZE_OFFSET_Y)
        self.MAZE_WIDTH = self.BLOCK_WIDTH * len(self.MATRIX[0])
        self.MAZE_HEIGHT = self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * len(self.MATRIX) 

    def DrawMaze(self, MazeSurface):
        for ROW in range(len(self.MATRIX)):
            for COLUMN in range(len(self.MATRIX[0])):
                # Only saves the position of each dot
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 0:
                    self.DOTS.append([(self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN),
                                     (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 4, 4])
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 1:
                    self.WALLS.append(pygame.draw.rect(MazeSurface, WHITE,
                                     [((self.BLOCK_WIDTH) * COLUMN),
                                     ((self.BLOCK_HEIGHT) * ROW), 
                                     self.BLOCK_WIDTH, self.BLOCK_HEIGHT]))

class Main(Maze):
    def __init__(self):
        # Inherits Maze class
        Maze.__init__(self)
        self.DIRECTION = ""
        self.SCORE = 0
        
    def Movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and not key[pygame.K_UP] \
                              and not key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.DIRECTION = "LEFT"
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not key[pygame.K_UP] \
                               and not key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.DIRECTION = "RIGHT"
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and not key[pygame.K_LEFT] \
                            and not key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.DIRECTION = "UP"
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN] and not key[pygame.K_LEFT] \
                              and not key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.DIRECTION = "DOWN"
            
    def ContinueMovement(self):
        if self.DIRECTION == "LEFT":
            CurrentRect.x -= SPEED
            self.WallDetection(-1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "RIGHT":
            CurrentRect.x += SPEED
            self.WallDetection(1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "UP":
            CurrentRect.y -= SPEED
            self.WallDetection(0, -1, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "DOWN":
            CurrentRect.y += SPEED
            self.WallDetection(0, 1, CurrentRect)

    def ChangeImage(self):
        global CurrentSurface
        if self.DIRECTION == "LEFT":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(PacManSurface, 180)
        if self.DIRECTION == "RIGHT":
            CurrentSurface = PacManSurface
        if self.DIRECTION == "UP":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(PacManSurface, 90)
        if self.DIRECTION == "DOWN":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(PacManSurface, 270)
        
    def Teleport(self):
        if CurrentRect.right < 0:
            CurrentRect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH + 20
        if CurrentRect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            CurrentRect.right = 0
    
    def WallDetection(self, x, y, CurrentRect):
        CurrentRect.right += x
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = CurrentRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if x < 0: 
                    CurrentRect.left = WALL.right
                elif x > 0:
                    CurrentRect.right = WALL.left
                break
        
        CurrentRect.top += y
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = CurrentRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if y < 0:
                    CurrentRect.top = WALL.bottom
                if y > 0:
                    CurrentRect.bottom = WALL.top
                break
            
    def EatDots(self):
        for ROW in range(len(self.MATRIX)):
            for COLUMN in range(len(self.MATRIX[0])):
                for DOT in self.DOTS:
                    CHOMP = CurrentRect.colliderect(DOT)
                    if CHOMP:
                        self.DOTS.remove(DOT)
                        self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] = 3
                        self.SCORE += 10
                        return str(self.SCORE)
                        
    def DrawDots(self):
        for POSITION in self.DOTS:
            X = POSITION[0] + 13
            Y = POSITION[1] + 13
            WIDTH = POSITION[2]
            HEIGHT = POSITION[3]
            pygame.draw.circle(MazeSurface, YELLOW, (X, Y), 
                               WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
            
    def EatGhosts(self):
        pass
    
    def EatPowerUp(self):
        pass
                
    def ShowText(self):
        Font = pygame.font.Font("emulogic.ttf", 15)
        OneUpText = Font.render("1UP", True, WHITE)
        OneUpTextRect = OneUpText.get_rect(center = (70, 10))
        OneUpScoreText = Font.render("00", True, WHITE)
        UpdateScore = Main.EatDots(self)
        if int(self.SCORE) > 0:
            OneUpScoreText = Font.render(UpdateScore, True, WHITE)
        OneUpScoreRect = OneUpScoreText.get_rect(center =
                                                ((SCREEN_WIDTH - 290) 
                                                // 2, 26))
        HighScoreText = Font.render("High Score", True, WHITE)
        HighScoreTextRect = HighScoreText.get_rect(center = 
                                                  (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, 10))
        HighScoreNumber = Font.render("00", True, WHITE)
        HighScoreNumberRect = HighScoreNumber.get_rect(center = 
                                                      ((SCREEN_WIDTH + 90) 
                                                      // 2, 26))
        
        SCREEN.blit(OneUpText, OneUpTextRect)
        SCREEN.blit(OneUpScoreText, OneUpScoreRect)
        SCREEN.blit(HighScoreText, HighScoreTextRect)
        SCREEN.blit(HighScoreNumber, HighScoreNumberRect)
        
    def PacManBite(self):
        SCREEN.blit(PacManStartSurface, PacManStartRect)
        pygame.display.update()
    
Player = Main()

BackgroundSurface = pygame.transform.scale(BackgroundSurface, 
                                          (Player.MAZE_WIDTH, 
                                           Player.MAZE_HEIGHT))
BackgroundRect = BackgroundSurface.get_rect()

MazeSurface = pygame.Surface((Player.MAZE_WIDTH, Player.MAZE_HEIGHT))
MazeRect = MazeSurface.get_rect(topleft = (Player.MAZE_OFFSET_X, 
                                           Player.MAZE_OFFSET_Y))
Player.DrawMaze(MazeSurface)

'''
pregame = True
while pregame:
    if key button pressed:
        pregame = False
    run = True
'''

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            Player.Movement()
            Player.ChangeImage()
            Player.Teleport()   
            
    Player.ContinueMovement()
    MazeSurface.blit(BackgroundSurface, BackgroundRect) 
    Player.DrawDots() 
    MazeSurface.blit(CurrentSurface, CurrentRect)
    Player.PacManBite()
    SCREEN.blit(MazeSurface, MazeRect)
    #SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    Player.ShowText()
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    
pygame.quit()
```

So I basically have two surfaces, the main screen and MazeSurface which I blit the maze, the dots, pacman, and background which I then blit them onto the main screen. So for some reason only one pacman image is blitted meaning I have PacManStartSurface which is PacMan with its mouth closed so just a circle and PacManSurface which is PacMan facing right or whatever direction im going in, basically I want to overlap them so that the PacMan images overlap and create the effect that it is biting or chomping the dots
[image: The pacman above only appears when I blit it onto the main screen but doesn't appear when I blit it onto the MazeSurface, how do I get them to overlap in the same position. The pacman above is PacManStartSurface and the pacman below is PacManSurface]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Please read [mcve] as well; it seems your code here is rather non-minimal and, more pressing, doesn't include anything to your problem: changing the background image. Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague: they won't have time (or be willing) to trawl hundreds of lines of code in order to perhaps find the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can change the scale of the background image like this:

```
backgroundImage = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImage, (width, height))
```

For the movement. You would speed up because the `Movement` function and the `ContinueMovement` function are being called and both of them are moving you so I made the `Movement` function not move you.

```
    def Movement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.DIRECTION = "LEFT"
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.DIRECTION = "RIGHT"
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.DIRECTION = "UP"
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.DIRECTION = "DOWN"
        
    def ContinueMovement(self):
        if self.DIRECTION == "LEFT":
            CurrentRect.x -= SPEED
            self.WallDetection(-1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "RIGHT":
            CurrentRect.x += SPEED
            self.WallDetection(1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "UP":
            CurrentRect.y -= SPEED
            self.WallDetection(0, -1, CurrentRect)
        if self.DIRECTION == "DOWN":
            CurrentRect.y += SPEED
            self.WallDetection(0, 1, CurrentRect)
```

You can see here that I replaced the long `if` statements with `elif` statements

I also replaced `Main.WallDetection(self, 0, 1, CurrentRect)` with this: `self.WallDetection(0, 1, CurrentRect)` because it's cleaner and more understandable

You should also consider making the Movement function take event like this: `def Movement(self, event):` and use event to check for button presses instead like this: `if event.button == PYGAME.K_LEFT`.

To draw the background so that it has exactly the same size as the maze you need to do this:

```
mazeHeight = (maze.BLOCK_HEIGHT + maze.MARGIN) * len(maze.MATRIX)
mazeWidth = (maze.BLOCK_WIDTH + maze.MARGIN) * len(maze.MATRIX[0])
backgroundImage = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImage, (mazeWidth, mazeHeight))
```

First you get the `mazeHeight`, which is done by multiplying the number of rows by the height of every block

Then you get the `mazeWidth` by multiplying the number of columns in one of the rows(doesn't matter which one) by the width of every block

Then finally, you set the size of the background image to be the `mazeWidth` and the `mazeHeight`

Note that the variable `maze` is an instance of the class `Maze` which is made like this: `maze = Maze()`

The `Maze` class should be like this:

```
class Maze:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DOTS = []
        self.WALLS = []
        self.BLOCK_SIZE = 22
        self.ROWS = 21
        self.COLUMNS = 20
        self.MARGIN = 3
        self.OFFSET_Y = 40
        # 0 - Dots
        # 1 - Walls
        # 2 - Power Up
        # 3 - Empty Space
        # 4 - Ghosts
        self.MATRIX = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], \
                      [3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3], \
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], \
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], \
                      [3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3], \
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    def DrawGrid(self):
        for ROW in range(self.ROWS):
            for COLUMN in range(self.COLUMNS - 1):
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 0:
                    self.DOTS.append(pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, YELLOW,
                                                        (((self.MARGIN + self.BLOCK_SIZE) * COLUMN) + self.BLOCK_SIZE/2,
                                                         ((self.MARGIN + self.BLOCK_SIZE) * ROW) + self.OFFSET_Y + self.BLOCK_SIZE/2),
                                                        2))
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 1:
                    self.WALLS.append(pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE,
                                                       (((self.MARGIN + self.BLOCK_SIZE) * COLUMN),
                                                        ((self.MARGIN + self.BLOCK_SIZE) * ROW) + self.OFFSET_Y,
                                                        self.BLOCK_SIZE, self.BLOCK_SIZE)))
```

I made a `self.OFFSET_Y` variable and I add `self.BLOCK_SIZE/2` to make it so that the dots are in the middle of the block

And I changed the scale of the `BackgroundSurface` like this:

```
BackgroundSurface = pygame.transform.scale(BackgroundSurface, ((Player.BLOCK_SIZE + Player.MARGIN) * len(Player.MATRIX[0]), (Player.BLOCK_SIZE + Player.MARGIN) * len(Player.MATRIX)))
```

I add the blocksize with the distance between every block and then I multiply them by the amount of blocks there is to get the size of all of the blocks combined

**EDIT:**

So I put `import time` at the top of the script because I used it to make the pacman bite

And I added three variables to the `__init__` in the `Main` class, like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    # Inherits Maze class
    Maze.__init__(self)
    self.timeBetweenBites = 0.2
    self.lastBiteTime = time.time()
    self.mouthOpen = False
    self.DIRECTION = ""
    self.SCORE = 0
```

I added `timeBetweenBites` which you can change to make the `Pacman` bite slower or faster

I added `lastBitTime` which is set to the current time every time the `Pacman` bites (Changes it's sprite)

And I added `mouthOpen` to know if the `Pacman's` mouth is open or closed

I also changed the `changeImage` function like this:

```
def ChangeImage(self):
    global CurrentSurface
    if self.DIRECTION == "LEFT":
        CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 180)
    if self.DIRECTION == "RIGHT":
        CurrentSurface = CurrentSurface
    if self.DIRECTION == "UP":
        CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 90)
    if self.DIRECTION == "DOWN":
        CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 270)
```

All I did was replace PacManSurface with CurrentSurface

And I changed the `PacManBite` function like this:

```
def PacManBite(self):
    global CurrentSurface

    if time.time() - self.lastBiteTime >= self.timeBetweenBites:
        self.lastBiteTime = time.time()

        if self.mouthOpen:
            CurrentSurface = PacManStartSurface
        else:
            CurrentSurface = PacManSurface

        self.mouthOpen = not self.mouthOpen

        if self.DIRECTION == "LEFT":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 180)
        if self.DIRECTION == "RIGHT":
            CurrentSurface = CurrentSurface
        if self.DIRECTION == "UP":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 90)
        if self.DIRECTION == "DOWN":
            CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 270)
```

What I'm doing here is checking if the current time minus the last time I changed the Pacman's surface is greater or equal to the time I want to spend before changing the Pacman's surface. And if that's true.

I set the last time I changed the Pacman's Surface to the current time because I will change it right now

Then I check if the Pacman's mouth is open. If it is I close it, if it's not I open it. Then I switch the Pacman's mouthOpen variable because I just switched the Pacman's surface

Then I set the rotation of the sprite to the rotation of the Pacman, and that's it.

I noticed that you forgot to put the `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)` in the `PinkGhost` class and that the `pygame.quit` line at the end of the script is pretty much useless

And that should work, thanks

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up really helpful,

Comment: So I have another issue, when I meant how do I scale the background maze image onto the maze I drew onto the screen, is there a way to scale it so that the background image literally overlaps the maze perfectly?

Comment: Ill try it out, I believe you are correct and know what Im referring to, I appreciate the time you took to look at my code and help me out.

Comment: So I tried it out and it doesnt scale exactly onto the maze.

Comment: When I blit it onto the screen, do I create a get_rect from the BackgroundImage?
So if I have
mazeHeight = maze.BLOCK_HEIGHT * len(maze.MATRIX)
mazeWidth = maze.BLOCK_WIDTH * len(maze.MATRIX[0])
backgroundImage = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImage, (mazeWidth, mazeHeight))
backgroundrect = backgroundImage.get_rect()

SCREEN.blit(backgroundImage, backgroundrect) ?

Comment: `backgroundrect = backgroundImage.get_rect() SCREEN.blit(backgroundImage, backgroundrect)` I think will be useless because you're just setting the rect of the image to it's rect. I think that the problem is with the `DrawGrid` function in the `Maze` class. You add lots of weird things while your drawing the grid. Like self.MARGIN and when you add a random 10. Are you sure that the background image is being drawn in the same position as the maze?

Comment: To make sure that that's happening you can make a `self.X` and a `self.Y` and use them to draw the grid. Then use the same variables to draw the `backgroundImage`

Comment: Btw, to make things look like `this`, just surround them with this character: `

Comment: Yeah you're right, regarding the way I'm drawing the grid, I'm not sure how to correctly draw it on there

Comment: What is the `MARGIN` variable?

Comment: You probably want the position to be like this: `(self.mazeX, self.mazeY, self.BLOCK_WIDTH, self.BLOCK_HEIGHT)`    `self.mazeX = self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN + self.OFFSET_X`    `self.mazeY = self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW + self.OFFSET_Y` then you would draw the backgroundImage like this. `WIN.blit(backgoundImage, Player.mazeX, Player.mazeY)` The `self.mazeX` and the `self.mazeY` variables need to be made in the `__init__()` function of the `Maze` class

Comment: MARGIN variable was to seperate the rectangles

Comment: What would self.OFFSET_X and self.OFFSET_Y be?

Comment: Could I give you my number so we can discuss this?

Comment: `self.OFFSET_X` and `self.OFFSET_Y` would be if you wanted to move the maze around

Comment: Yes you can give me your number but only if this doesn't work

Comment: Right, so I re updated the code, I didn't draw the circle inside the Maze function, I only stored the positions x and y, I created another function that blit them onto the MazeSurface which displays them

Comment: Im having another issue where one image isn't overlapped onto the other meaning I have two images from the start of the code, PacManStartSurface and PacManSurface, the reason I want to overlap them is because I want to create the effect that PacMan is chomping. But when I blit them onto the screen, they don't overlap, instead one hovers above the other.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I updated my answer

Comment: You probably need to call `SCREEN.fill(backgroundColor)` every frame and `backgroundColor` would be a color of your choice. If you do that You'll need to redraw everything every frame

Comment: Right So that's what I did I can repost it but one of the surfaces isnt being drawn on the same surface, so im using mazesurface to draw the pacman images but only one shows up

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean here. but if you edit your question and change the script that's there, I might be able to help

Comment: The animation for the PacMan seems to be off, I followed what you said checking the previous time with the current time in order to open and close the mouth, not sure because I placed it inside the PacMan class and not outside of it causes it to not create a smooth transition

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure about what you mean by a smooth transition, so like is the animation like spending more time on mouthopen than on mouthclosed for example?
Also, if you can update the script in the question so that I can see if you did anything wrong.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't displat the animation smoothly I followed what you said with regards to using the time library, but I did display the code in another question just not sure if it has to do with when I declare them in a PacMan class or outside PacMan class

Comment: I don't think that that is the reason for the animation not being smooth

Comment: If by saying that the animation is not smooth you mean that the chomping effect just looks kind of bad, you can make the pacman open and close his mouth faster, or you can add like a different image where the pacmans mouth is half open

Comment: So what I did, I managed to find 3 images of the object, the first image is just the mouth closed, the second image is opening the mouth, the third image is the mouth wide open, I created a switch to flip through the images in the order 1, 2, 3 then 3, 2, 1 simultaneously  to create the effect, the only other main issue I have is the performance of the game, it sometimes starts off slow then goes faster but I'll look into it

Comment: I think I know why you're getting problems with performance, you loop through every block two times every single frame. I don't think that you need to do that in the `Eat dots` and `Eat energizer` functions. You should store the row and column of every dot and powerup in their lists like `self.ENERGIZER.append([(row, column), ((self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN), (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 14, 14)])` then only loop through the `dots` or `energizers`  check if they collide like this: `CurrentRect.colliderect(DOT[1])` and if they do, do this: `self.MATRIX[Dot[0][0]][Dot[0][1]] = 3`

Comment: Also I noticed that `CurrentRect` and `CurrentSurface` don't need to be defined at the top of the script they can just be defined as `self.CurrentRect` and `self.CurrentSurface` in the `Main` class which would also mean that you don't need to write `global Current...` at the top of some functions anymore. (It's recommended to not use global variables, global constants are okay though). Also if you can't read the code in the above comment copy and paste it in a random empty area in your editor so that you can read it easier

Comment: Yeah I was able to fix that, right now the issue I'm facing is trying to figure out a way to reroute the ghost when they've been eaten. Not asking for code just asking do you know of an efficient way to make it go back to its starting position, like setting a destination and making the ghost go back to its starting position after it has been eaten by pacman

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but if you're trying to make pathfinding to make the ghosts find the fastest way to go back you might want to look into the A* pathfinding algorithm or google Alternatives to the a* pathfinding algorithm

Comment: so I managed to integrate a shortest path algorithm, so once I have that Path from the position the ghost died to the starting position, how do I know which direction I move. Say I have a list Coordinates = [ (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (4,6) ], I set X1, Y1 = Coordinates[0] and X2, Y2 = Coordinates[1] and check if X1 +- 1 = X2, I know to move left or right and if Y1 -+ = Y2  I know to move up or down.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is how do I know how to navigate from that initial position? Mines only works when I'm right in a coordinates position, so if I'm at [1][4], the position is (25, 100) since 1 * 25 = 25 and 4 * 25 = 100, but when I'm at an uneven position like (37, 200), I still get an integer by doing // 25, but I think it gets thrown off by the logic I'm doing

Comment: Which algorithm are you using to do the pathfinding?

Comment: Its called a Shortest Path Algorithm 
Heres the link: https://python.plainenglish.io/difficult-python-question-9-shortest-paths-in-a-maze-361d51c53575

Comment: So I have a Matrix which is 19x21, so if a Ghosts Maze Position is [9][7], 9 to the right, 7 down, it translates into 9 x 25, = 175 7 x 25 = 225, where 25 is the side of the blocks. It ranges from one block to other so when you wanna go from [9][7] to [10][7] you're going 25 to the right so from 225 to 249 you're still in [9][7] but once it hits 250 you're at [10][7[ because 250 // 25 = 10. Don't want to make it sound complex lol but I'm almost there I just need to handle it when it's not on those exact coordinates.

Comment: I think I managed to fix it, now all of a sudden my pacman character seems to go slower than the ghost, I have uploaded my code to github if you wanna test it out and give me some feeback as I am also trying to optimize the code, not sure because its complex it causes it the character to run slow. https://github.com/Navar21/Python/tree/main/PyGame

Comment: I downloaded the game and I think that pacman and the ghost move at the same speed. But you should make it so that you don't have to keep on holding a button for the pacman to keep on moving, make the pacman move even if you're not pressing any button and make it so that if I for example press the up arrow and there's a wall above me a one second timer starts and as long as that timer hasn't ended yet keep on checking every frame if there isn't a wall above me, if so make the pacman go up. I think that will make the game feel a lot smoother.

Comment: Yeah they do move at the same speed but I'm trying to see if I can change logic when PacMan eats the pellets one by one, since I am checking both x and y coordinates with respect to position of pellet and pacman. I will consider it, I also think that I need to fix when PacMan eats an energizer, I think I am checking the center if they overlap, but as soon as I touch an energizer, it automatically eats it before it overlaps